# Remove outer shadow of powerpoint table

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to remove the outer shadow property of a table.

I have used the below code but it isn't working.

```
with table.rows(x).columns (x).shape.shadow
.visible =false
end with
```

Comment: What error you received or what went wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If your table shape object is set to oShp this will return the shadow property for the entire table shape as opposed to individual cells:

```
oShp.Shadow
```

But it appears that there is a bug (there are many in the latest table object model) writing to this property as this is ignored:

```
oShp.Shadow = msoFalse
```

I was going to suggest using CommandBars.ExecuteMso but there doesn't appear to be a control ID for shadow = none. As a result, I can't see a workaround for this other than the dreaded SendKeys which is always the least desirable option.

You could use this workaround:

```
oShp.Shadow.Transparency = 1
```

Comment: Not directly using the Shadow.Visible property, no. But you could use this to hide it: 

oShp.Shadow.Transparency = 1

Comment: Thanks Pandi. If you're happy, could you mark the solution as useful please :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could force the shadow to be turned off by applying a pre-defined Microsoft Style to the Table object:

```
oShp.Table.ApplyStyle "{2D5ABB26-0587-4C30-8999-92F81FD0307C}"
```

Shape style ID's can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh273476%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396